# 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function' keeps showing up for different lines of code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to take a set of text, and when I hit a button have it change to a different set of text. I have been trying a lot of different methods, and cannot seem to get it to work. Here is a working [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/metalfoley/nvbyp3wm/1/).

I keep getting 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function' for the line

```
var $rep = $update.textContent.substring(1);
```

I have changed this line of code, but will the get the same error on a different line of code within the same function.

```
function createAnswers() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        var $update = $(".answers p")[i];
        var $rep = $update.textContent.substring(1);
        console.log($rep);
        var answerText = document.createTextNode(randomImage.randomAnswers[i]);
        if (usedImages.length >= 1) {
            $rep.replaceWith(answerText);
        }
            $update.appendChild(answerText);
    }
}
```

I am still pretty new at Javascript, so I may be missing something very obvious. Any constructive criticism will be helpful.

Comment: That seems to indicate that there aren't 3 elements matching the selector. Also, `$rep.replaceWith()` seems to be an error (it's a string?), you're using native methods and jQuery methods randomly, but you seem to have a native DOM node.

Comment: `$rep` is a string, while function `.replaceWith` works with DOM nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Your function should look like:

```
function createAnswers() {
    var i,
        $answers = $(".answers p");

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        var $update = $answers[i];
        var $rep = $update.textContent.substring(1);
        var answerText = document.createTextNode(randomImage.randomAnswers[i]);

        if (usedImages.length >= 1) {
            $update.textContent = $update.textContent.replace($rep, answerText.textContent);
        }

        $update.appendChild(answerText);
    }
}
```

You do not need to use jQuery functions after `var $update = $(".answers p")[i];`, because $update becomes an DOM node.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but all this did was append the same text node onto the existing one. I figured it out though.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Thanks everybody for the help. I realized I needed to specify the use of text nodes, and updating the text node directly. Here is my final code:

```
function createAnswers() {
    var i,
        $update;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        $update = $(".answers p")[i];
        console.log($update);
        var answerText = document.createTextNode(randomImage.randomAnswers[i]);
        if (usedImages.length === 0) {
            $update.appendChild(answerText);
        }
        else {
            $update.childNodes[1].nodeValue = randomImage.randomAnswers[i];
        }
    }
}
```